# Sql and PHP by AJAX send value to another page for process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code that use for return question by ajax from list of question throw sql

```
<form id="reg-form3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list primary push-bottom">
        <?
        $db['db_host']="localhost";
        $db['db_user']="root";
        $db['db_pass']="";
        $db['db_name']="zadli";
        foreach ($db as $key => $value){
            define(strtoupper($key), $value);
        }

        $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if($con){
        mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES "utf8";');
            //  echo "<h1>we are connected</h1>";
        }
        else {
            die("eroor conection".mysqli_error($con));
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `training_questions` WHERE category_id=$cat_id ";
        $query_quize=  mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_quize)) {
            $qustio=$row['id'];
            $i=$row['id'];
            echo $i;
            ?>
            <input name="start_time" type="hidden" id="start_time" value="<?= time() ?>">
            <input name="training_id" type="hidden" id="training_id" value="<?= $_GET['cat'] ?>">
            <li><input name="btn-save" type="submit"  id="btn-save4" value="<?=$qustio ?>">
                <?
                $queryt = "SELECT * FROM `training_questions` WHERE id=$i ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
                $query_quizet=  mysqli_query($con, $queryt);
                while ($rowt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_quizet)) {
                ?>
                    <input name="questions_id" type="hidden" id="questions_id" value="<?= $rowt['id'] ?>">
                <?
                }
                $txt_clean = strip_tags($row['question_text']);
                $final_txt = cutText($txt_clean, 90);
                echo $final_txt.'...';
                ?>
                </input>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

the code below for list of the question

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //using $.ajax() function

    $(document).on('submit', '#reg-form3', function(){
        var op1=document.getElementById( "btn-save4" );
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxquastion3.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#btn-save").hide();
                $("#btn-save2").show();
                $('#reg-form').attr('id', 'reg-form2');

                $("#quas").fadeOut(500).hide(function(){
                    $("#quas").fadeIn(500).show(function(){
                        $("#quas").html(data);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this code for send the value by ajax to another page

the page ajaxquastion3.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require ("../include/db.class.php");
require ("../include/config.php");
require ("../include/function.php");

if($_SESSION['id'] != ''){
    $sql_user = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=:id";
    $data_user[id] = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result_user = $pdo->pdoGetRow($sql_user, $data_user);
    $user_id = $result_user['id'];
    $user_paid = $result_user['paid'];
    $user_full_name = $result_user['first_name']." ".$result_user['middle_name']." ".$result_user['last_name'];
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

$start_time=$_POST['start_time'];
$training_id=$_POST['training_id'];
$questions_id=$_POST['questions_id'];
$question_text=$_POST['question_text'];

$db['db_host']="localhost";
$db['db_user']="root";
$db['db_pass']="";
$db['db_name']="zadli";

foreach ($db as $key => $value){
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($con){
    mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES "utf8";');
    //  echo "<h1>we are connected</h1>";
}
else {
    die("eroor conection".mysqli_error($con));
}
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Succedd !!!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td>
            <td><?php echo $training_id ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td>
            <td><?php echo $questions_id ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td>
            <td><?php echo $x ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?
    $queryq = "SELECT * FROM `training_questions` WHERE  id=$questions_id";
    $query_chek=  mysqli_query($con, $queryq);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_chek)) {
        $test=$row['id'];
        echo '<h4>'.$row['question_text'].'</h4>';
        ?>
        <input name="questions_id" type="hidden" id="questions_id" value="<?= $test ?>">
        <input name="training_id" type="hidden" id="training_id" value="<?= $training_id ?>">

        <div class="radio">
            <input name="option" type="radio" class="styled" id="option1" value="1">
            <label for="option1">
                <strong>أ -</strong>
                <?= $row['option1'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input name="option" type="radio" class="styled" id="option2" value="2">
            <label for="option2">
                <strong>ب -</strong>
                <?= $row['option2'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input name="option" type="radio" class="styled" id="option3" value="3">
            <label for="option3">
                <strong>ج -</strong>
                <?= $row['option3'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input name="option" type="radio" class="styled" id="option4" value="4">
            <label for="option4">
                <strong>د -</strong>
                <?= $row['option4'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

My problem is that we i submit  the form the question appear is the last question in db any question i submit the just the last question is appear

Comment: The line in **ajaxquestion3.php** - `$queryq = "SELECT * FROM \`training_questions\` WHERE  id=$questions_id";` is referencing `$questions_id` which has not been set, thus this query will always return the first record.  Also, passing data like this directly for SQL execution is dangerous.  You might want to look into prepared statements for safer querying.

Comment: i forget some code please see it now and help me

Comment: Try this.  Instead of setting those `<input>` elements inside the form with name -- try something like :  https://jsfiddle.net/9rsv2dow/  .  Essentially, you can wrap that in, and send the value `datatopost` in your ajax request.  Your problem is that all your input fields have the same name so how can it tell the difference -- but you want to submit data with a name that is consistent.  My fiddle link shows you how this can be done to fix up your first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating all of your `<input name="questions_id"` and `<input name="btn-save"` elements in same `<form>`

So basically when you submit your form, the value of last element with `name="questions_id"` will be processed...

So one of your solution(the quickest one) is to bring your `<form>` elements also in your loop and create different `<forms>`

But I also have some problems with your logic:

1- When you are storing `$row['id']` in `$qustio` why are you again storing `$row['id']` in `$i`? Why don't you use `$qustio` for the same purpose?

2- first you have this query: `$query = "SELECT * FROM`training_questions`WHERE category_id=$cat_id ";` and then later in your loop you have again the same query `$queryt = "SELECT * FROM`training_questions`WHERE id=$i ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";` which because of `LIMIT 1` will only return **1** record and you are using another loop for this query which you totally do not need it in the first place. So I will also remove these extra lines of code and the result will be:

3- I assume `$cat_id` is same `$_GET['cat']` so I will replace `$_GET['cat']` with `$cat_id` in your code. If my assumption was wrong then please kindly replace it back in this line: `<input name="training_id" type="hidden" id="training_id" value="<?= $_GET['cat'] ?>">`

4- since `id` should be unique in the `document` and you have different elements in your loop which will generate different copy of them with same `id`, I replace the `id` with `class` so I can reference them in jquery

```
<ul class="nav nav-list primary push-bottom">
    <?
    $db['db_host']="localhost";
    $db['db_user']="root";
    $db['db_pass']="";
    $db['db_name']="zadli";
    foreach ($db as $key => $value){
        define(strtoupper($key), $value);
    }

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if($con){
        mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES "utf8";');
        //  echo "<h1>we are connected</h1>";
    }
    else {
        die("eroor conection".mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `training_questions` WHERE category_id=$cat_id ";
    $query_quize=  mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_quize)) {
        $qustio=$row['id'];
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $qustio;?>
            <form>
                <input name="start_time" type="hidden" class="start_time" value="<?= time() ?>">
                <input name="training_id" type="hidden" class="training_id" value="<?= $cat_id ?>">
                <input name="btn-save" type="submit"  class="btn-save4" value="<?=$qustio ?>">
                <input name="questions_id" type="hidden" class="questions_id" value="<?= $qustio ?>">
                <?
                $txt_clean = strip_tags($row['question_text']);
                $final_txt = cutText($txt_clean, 90);
                echo $final_txt.'...';
                ?>
            </form>
        </li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

And then in your jquery, you can reference the element of each form like this: `$(this).find()`

I do not know what does this line do `$('#reg-form').attr('id', 'reg-form2');` But since I did not find any code related to it, I just removed it, If you need this line, I think you have to find another way to work with it like using `class` instead of `id` because of the uniqueness of the `id` which I mentioned before

Also I did not find and element with this `id` in your code: `#quas` but I assume you have an element like a `<div>` with this ID...

If this element is in your `loop` again you have to use `class` instead of `id` but if you have only one copy of it in your code, then using `id` is OK. and since I assume you only have one copy of it in your code, I will leave it as it is

So your jquery will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //using $.ajax() function

    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        var op1 = $(this).find('.btn-save4');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxquastion3.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).find('.btn-save').hide();
                $(this).find('.btn-save2').show();

                $("#quas").fadeOut(500).hide(function(){
                    $("#quas").fadeIn(500).show(function(){
                        $("#quas").html(data);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

And at last your ajaxquastion3.php file

First of all, you are using both `PDO` and `mysqli` in your code! Why is that? It's better to use one if you are using both of them to connect to the same database.

Then in your loop you have `$test=$row['id'];` which again is not necessary and you can use `$row['id']` instead of `$test`

And you have these four `<div class="radio">` which you can avoid them and use a `for loop` to populate them

So your ajaxquastion3.php file will be like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require ("../include/db.class.php");
require ("../include/config.php");
require ("../include/function.php");

if($_SESSION['id'] != ''){
    $sql_user = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=:id";
    $data_user[id] = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result_user = $pdo->pdoGetRow($sql_user, $data_user);
    $user_id = $result_user['id'];
    $user_paid = $result_user['paid'];
    $user_full_name = $result_user['first_name']." ".$result_user['middle_name']." ".$result_user['last_name'];
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

$start_time=$_POST['start_time'];
$training_id=$_POST['training_id'];
$questions_id=$_POST['questions_id'];
$question_text=$_POST['question_text'];

$db['db_host']="localhost";
$db['db_user']="root";
$db['db_pass']="";
$db['db_name']="zadli";

foreach ($db as $key => $value){
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($con){
    mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES "utf8";');
    //  echo "<h1>we are connected</h1>";
}
else {
    die("eroor conection".mysqli_error($con));
}
?>

<div class="form-group">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Succedd !!!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td>
        <td><?php echo $training_id ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td>
        <td><?php echo $questions_id ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td>
        <td><?php echo $x ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?
$queryq = "SELECT * FROM `training_questions` WHERE  id=$questions_id";
$query_chek=  mysqli_query($con, $queryq);
$arrLEtter = ['أ', 'ب', 'ج', 'د'];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_chek)) {
    echo '<h4>'.$row['question_text'].'</h4>';
    ?>
    <input name="questions_id" type="hidden" id="questions_id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
    <input name="training_id" type="hidden" id="training_id" value="<?= $training_id ?>">
    <?php
    for($iCnt = 1; $iCnt <= 4; $iCnt++){
        ?>
        <div class="radio">
            <input name="option" type="radio" class="styled" id="option<?=$iCnt?>" value="<?=$iCnt?>">
            <label for="option<?=$iCnt?>">
                <strong><?=$arrLEtter[$iCnt -1]?> -</strong>
                <?= $row['option'.$iCnt] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
<? } ?>
</div>
```

There are some missing variables or code section in your code which I think you have removed to make your example minimal. So I think this code should work if you include those missing parts to it...

Comment: I will tray and back to you

Comment: @Eng-AbdallahJomaa :) you are welcome. If this answer helped you to solve your problem please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer and give it an up-vote...